# Solr: Getting facets without exact match

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet

Let's assume I search for "developer" in a field, I get 1000 results & for "Php Developer" I get 1500 results.

My query returns facets like:

- Php Developer (16)
- Developer (15)
- .Net Developer (14)

The above facets means that there are 16 documents with the exact match of "Php Developer" & 15 documents with the exact match of "Web Developer" and so on.

I want these facets to be representing the "actual number of search results" if someone searches for "Developer".

- Php Developer (1500)
- .Net Developer (1100)
- Developer (1000)

How can I make my facets to represent the number of results NOT the number of exact matches.

Comment: A few questions - what field are you faceting on? and are there other fields that you are searching?

Comment: I am faceting on 'Title_exact' field. I am searching 'Title' and 'Description' fields.

Answer (score 2):

**My Advice** - use your search as it is working currently for you. The facets on partial match seems a bit confusing. People expect partial matches on search results, but exact match on the facets. Facets are more of a "browse" behaviour which allow the users to drill down to specifics. Ambiguity in facets may not allow the users to slice properly.

*However, if you still want to use what you are asking for here are some thoughts.*

As you mention, the faceting and searching work against different fields, so that can be a cause of this difference.

Faceting works on indexed values, not [stored values](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview#Facet_Indexing)

So, in order to achieve what you need, you would have to use the exact same fields for searching and faceting.

Also, if you have a catch-all field (copyfield), that would cause this kind of behaviour.